# jQuery UI datepicker with custom dynamic date range

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, date, datepicker

I'm using [jQuery UI datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) plugin in one of my application developed with [CodeIgniter](http://www.codeigniter.com/). And it's working fine they way I expected it to work.

Now I'm working on a new form where I need a custom date range for the datepicker field which user can choose a date from. So far when user comes to the form it's showing a year dropdown field. And once user choose a year from the dropdown my functionality is appending some new fields to the form. So one field is `Date Applied`, which is a text field and there I'm initializing the jQuery UI datepicker and it's showing the datepicker when user focus on that field.

So this is what I have done so far. Now let me explain about the problem. As per user year selection from very first step I want to restrict `Date Applied` selection. If user selected `2014` then I want to allow user to choose `1 Oct, 2014` to `30 Sep, 2015`. So `month` range will always `1 Oct` - `30 Sep` and year will be `selected year` - `selected year + 1`.

Some more examples:

- 2010 - `1 Oct, 2010` to `30 Sept, 2011`
- 2015 - `1 Oct, 2015` to `30 Sept, 2016`
- 2016 - `1 Oct, 2016` to `30 Sept, 2017`

Please let me know if anyone can help me how to set these custom dynamic date range in the jQuery UI datepicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm able to make it working. Below is the codes that solve my problem.

```
var firstYear    = userYear;
var endYear      = userYear + 1;
$( ".addDatePickerTransfer" ).datepicker({
   yearRange: "'" + firstYear + ":" + endYear + "'",
   minDate: new Date(firstYear, 10 - 1, 1),
   maxDate: new Date(endYear, 9 - 1, 30)
});
```

NOTE: userYear is the value, I received from user selected year value.

Answer (score 0):

As in [this example](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range) on datepicker close event set new `minDate` and `maxDate` values.

```
$("#to").datepicker({
  onClose: function(selectedDate) {
    $("#from").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
  }
});
```

Comment: I have only one field `Date Applied` and I want to set the date selection range on that field only.

Comment: @DeepakBiswal You do not provide any code, can't tell if you have one field or 100...

Comment: I have mentioned it in my description `Date Applied`. Anyways I got my answer and posting in a few. Thanks for your direction!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the year range using this option per documentation here http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-yearRange

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({
 yearRange: "2002:2012"
 });
```

**or**

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({
 yearRange: "-50:+0"//last 50 year
});
```